Selecting correct extent for cartopy image
I have an image with a defined size (say, 50km x 40km) and I want to be able to place it centered at any (lon, lat) point in my map.
The extent in PlateCarre units will thus be very different if is centered at the pole or at the equator and, strictly speaking, the image is not even a rectangle in (lat, lon) coordinates. How can I add this image to my projection?
Even better if there is a solution that would allow consideration of an image that is rotated (columns not aligned with meridians).
